# Update the items in QTreeView and QListView

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QTreeView to show folders and QListView to show the contents of the folders in the file system but there is one issue here. When I made some changes on the file system for example rename or delete a file, these changes never represented in these two widgets. What should I do? Also, I should mention here, I am using QFileSytsemModel to show and works with filesystem. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::ListDirectory(QString arg_smb_path)
{
    o_directorySystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_directorySystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
    o_directorySystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->treeView->setModel(o_directorySystemModel);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);


    o_fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_fileSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files);
    o_fileSystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->listView->setModel(o_fileSystemModel);
    ui->listView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
}

void MainWindow::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString Path = o_directorySystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
    ui->listView->setRootIndex(o_fileSystemModel->setRootPath(Path));
}
```

Comment: What model are you using? `QFileSystemModel`?

Comment: Yes. I am using QFileSystemModel.

Comment: could you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also you can probably have a look at that: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#Option-enum

Some of the options are related to Watching folders, etc..

Comment: Also I put my code here.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't see anything wrong so far. What version of Qt are you using? Which OS? which compiler?

Comment: I am using Qt5, Windows and MSVC compiler.

Comment: Qt 5.14, 5.15, 5.what? I know it's a bit tedious but from working actively with Qt, even if they try to do their best to have consistent behaviour across systems and versions, it's not always the case. ans sometime comparing the Qt sources of 2 versions is helping to understand why that bit of code no longer works after an upgrade.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.14.1 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

in python :
self.listview.update()

shoulde be same in c++
ui->listview.update()

try it